# Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в Python почему код не хочет правильно работать

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print('Проверка существования  треугольника')
a = input(' первая сторона=')
b = input(' вторая сторона=')
c = input(' третья сторона=')

a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])

if c < b+a:  
    print('треугольник существует')
elif c == b+a:   
    print('треугольник не  существует')
else: 
    print('треугольник  не существует')
```

Comment: нижнюю часть кода с проверкой можно заменить одной строкой `print(f'треугольник{(" не" if (c < b + a)  else "")} cуществует')`

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

В переменных `a, b, c` у вас строки, а не число

Их надо преобразовать в число с помощью `int`

```
a = int(input(' первая сторона=')) 
b = int(input(' вторая сторона=')) 
c = int(input(' третья сторона='))
```

Comment: спасибо большое)